# Is iPad browser crashing issue (on download of ~7 MB of images) valid for audio files as well?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, browser, mobile-safari

iPad browser crashes if we try to download images beyond 6.5 MB of size. Is this size related to generic browser cache or its only specific to images? In case if I want to load 5-6 audio files on some user interaction, can I download them without any size limitation issues? OR should I consider that 6.5 MB is the maximum browser cache allowed and size of all the images and audio downloaded should not exceed 6.5 MB?

Comment: What kind of images with what resolution? File size is meaningless, what counts is the resolution of each image. An uncompressed 6.5 MB JPEG may well take up dozens or hundreds of times the actual file size in memory

Comment: Thanks for replying! but my query is not related to the type of images. Sorry if it is conveying the wrong message.
Its a known fact the iPad browser crashes once you try to download more than 6-7 MB of images on the same HTML page. Now my query is, is this size limitation valid only for images or does it include the audio file's size as well? For eg : Should browser crash if I download 4 MB of images and 3 MB of audio files??

Answer (score 0):

I think the limit only applies to images, and not other things like audio.
I did a test tonight at Staples on their demos and I can confirm you that my HTML5/Construct2 video game (webapp, so into the Safari browser) does not seem to apply to iPad Air and iPad Air 2, hopefully! The very same thing did not worked on either iPhone4S and any iPad Mini. However, I don't know if the hardcoded memory limit has been augmented on Air and Air2, or completely left away... Somebody knows?

Comment: Pretty old question of mine for iPad 1st generation. Don't think holds even now.